# How can I change the color of buttons?

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm developing my first application in vaadin and I can't to change the color of my button (want them to blacks). I'm using  my custom theme that inherited from Reindeer.

I try in this way:

```
    buttonSetting = new Button();
    buttonSetting.setIcon(new ThemeResource("images/icons/16px/setting.png"));
    buttonSetting.addStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_SMALL);
    buttonSetting.addStyleName(Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLACK);
```

but doesn't work, How can I do?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563322/java-apple-default-look-and-feel-how-to-set-color-of-a-button

Comment: Chec this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393385/java-how-to-changing-text-color-on-button

Comment: try using 
`buttonSetting.setStyleName(Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLACK);`
`buttonSetting.addStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_SMALL);`

Comment: I try to change order bur still doesn't work

Comment: @Marco It's not an order that matters. Have you tried to use `setStyleName` (not `addStyleName`) for `LAYOUT_BLACK`? `setStyleName` will override previous style.

Comment: I tried also setStyleName but doesn't work yet

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLACK should be the style name of a component containing the Button.

```
public class AdminBar extends CustomComponent {

private final HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();

public AdminBar(Lang lang) {
    setCompositionRoot(layout);
    setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    layout.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    setStyleName(Reindeer.LAYOUT_BLACK);
    Button button = new Button("I'm a Button");
    button.setStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_SMALL);
    layout.addComponent(button);
}
}
```

If you set the style name of the HorizontalLayout instead of the AdminBar, the whole layout will be black.